# Decoding animal language (dolphins etc)

Tags: zoology, experimental-design, intelligence, language, research-design

I have this idea about how we perhaps could decode animal vocabularies that I would like to have some input on.

The idea is to design an experiment/challenge where we could predict roughly what has to be communicated between two individuals of a species in order to succeed with the challenge, for instance two dolphins.

An example could be a colored button that one dolphin has to push to give both dolphins a treat, but where only the other dolphin (the one that can't push it) gets to know which is the correct one. This should encourage them to communicate what to do and specifically what colored button to press. And by doing this kind of experiment several times we could perhaps extract what sounds represent for instance "red". And so on we could build up a basic vocabulary. What do you think about that? =)

The main idea is to in some way encourage two individuals to communicate something that we by design can infer from the outcome of the experiment. If first training one individual in solving a challenge and then letting it observe another individual that has no clue how to solve it, it should encourage it to communicate the solution, if it's sufficient intelligent that is.

Could it be done you think? I wish I had the resources to try this out myself but alas I don't. I'm all out of dolphins. I have asked a few researchers for input but they don't seem to think this is possible since no animal are intelligent enough and have any kind of language in the way we think about it. But personally I don't fully buy that. I still think a few animals would be possible subjects for a test like this, such as dolphins.

Comment: You know what? You ought to give it a shot!

Comment: All my dolphins have escaped!

Comment: Then you don't need such mechanisms to understand why they did so ;)

Comment: The design of scientific experiments is an art!

Comment: No, that's not really a good design. First, it is more than unlikely that dolphins have a "word" for "red". It would sound like a very advanced vocabulary word already. Second, it is unclear how you would determine that whatever sound you're hearing aren't meaning "I am distressed" or "I am excited to get food" or "I want sex" or whatever other meaning such sound could have. You would at least need a control.

Comment: If it's useful for dolphins to communicate a color in some way I assume their "language" should include some "representation" for this? Or do you suggest that no animal except human can communicate anything other than basic needs and states of mind? Perhaps that's true but have we _really_ looked for it? Perhaps we are blinded by our preconceptions. Also, my idea is to repeat the same experiment many times to filter out the sounds that always turn up, to be able to exclude all non-essential sounds.